# Map not displaying on webpage (Google Maps/Places API)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-places-api

this is my first HTML/Javascript project and I'm having some trouble. The goal is to take an address and simply display a map with markers on stores within 500m of that address. The issue is that I get a blank page; nothing shows up at all. Most of this code is copied verbatim from Google's examples, so I don't know what could be wrong.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Make a Good Impression</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKeyGoesHere"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="coffee_and_donuts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="map" style="float:left;width:30%;height 100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

coffee_and_donuts.js:

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var DESTINATION_ADDRESS = "New York, New York";
var destination_LatLng;


// get the destination's LatLng object
geocoder.geocode( {'address': DESTINATION_ADDRESS}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
  {
      destination_LatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
  }
});


// feed the destination's LatLng object to the places API to find the nearest stores

var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize2() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: destination_LatLng,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: destination_LatLng,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['store']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

initialize2();
```

Comment: Make a fiddle and I can help out

Comment: I didn't know about this tool. Very cool. http://jsfiddle.net/8hga1h52/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `initialize2();` from within your geocode function callback:

```
// get the destination's LatLng object
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': DESTINATION_ADDRESS}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
      {
          destination_LatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
          initialize2();
      }
    });
```

The problem is that you were trying to initialise the map before the geocoder had finished.

You can also put this all in one link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The map still isn't rendering though.

Comment: You also can't use 100% height for a floated div unless you give a height to its container, set it to 600px or something and it should show

Comment: There it is. Thank you!

Comment: `createmarker()` isn't defined in the code you provided.